# how to remove the border from the last list item and select :nth-child (multiple items)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

How do i select the third link to remove the right border? The first three are text links and I want to remove the right-border from the last text link.  The last two are buttons.  I don't want the borders between or at the end of the buttons either. I can't believe how much trouble I am having with this.  Its probably a simple solution but it's taking me forever to figure it out for browsers.  Thanks.

Javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("ul.subnavigation li:nth-child(3)").addClass("last-child");
    });
        </script>
```

HTML

```
<ul class="subnavigation">
                <li><a href="$sign_in_url" id="Program" rel="nofollow" ></a>Program </li>
                <li><a href="$sign_in_url" id="About" rel="nofollow" >About </a> </li>
                <li><a href="$sign_in_url" id="faq" rel="nofollow" >How to/FAQs</a> </li>
                <li><a href="$sign_in_url" id="register" rel="nofollow" class="btn_register hide-text">Register</a> </li>
                <li><a href="$sign_in_url" id="signin" rel="nofollow" class="btn_signin hide-text">Sign in</a></li></ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.subnavigation {  
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    font-size:16px;
    color:#333333; 
    list-style:none;
    }

.subnavigation li{
    display:inline;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
}

.subnavigation li:last-child{
    display:inline;
    border-right:0px;
}


.last-child {border:none;}

.subnavigation li a   {
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;
    line-height:18px;

    }

.subnavigation li a:hover {
    color:#2274ac;
    }


.subnavigation a.btn_register {
    background:url(../images/nt_btn-register.png) no-repeat;
    width:66px; 
    height:23px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 5px 0 0;
    float:right;
    text-indent:-999px;
    }

.subnavigation a.btn_signin {
    background:url(../images/nt_btn-signin.png) no-repeat;
    width:56px; 
    height:23px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 10px 0 5px;
    float:right;
    text-indent:-999px;
    }

.hide-text {
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

[JS FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/Chris22/A46Ka/1/)

Comment: You want to remove the border from `How To/Faq's`?

Comment: Yes as well as after the Register button image

Comment: `nth-child` selectors are CSS3 only, so if you're not in a CSS3 browser you're going to have problems. What you can do, however, is use jQuery to add a 'borderless' class to those elements and supply a css declaration of `.borderless{border-right:none;}`

Comment: isn't that what I'm doing in the javascript snippet above?`$("ul.subnavigation li:nth-child(3)").addClass("last-child");`

Comment: that is correct, however, you're only selecting 1 element, whereas you want multiple elements, use a `comma separated list` in the selector. `last-child` on multiple elements will become confusing, especially if this project ever goes into another developers hands, which is why I suggested what I did, it should be something like `$('ul.subnavigation li:nth-child(2), ul.subnavigation li:nth-child(3)').addClass('borderless')`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, thanks.  I didn't try the multiple selection yet, because it appears I'm unable to target the correct li -- the border is still there after the third `li`

Comment: [have a look at this jsFiddle then.](http://jsfiddle.net/quKuX/)

Comment: Thanks, for the fiddle. the border is still there after the register link, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css to be more specific

```
li.last-child {border-right:0px;}
```

then jQuery you can use [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get `li` elements of index 2> to remove the right border

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("ul.subnavigation li").slice(2).addClass("last-child");
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A46Ka/2/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery. Here it is with plain CSS - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/A46Ka/4/)

```
.subnavigation li:nth-child(n+3) {
    border: 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

The above code will not work in older IE-s - [***:nth-child* browser support**](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child)

To make it backward compatible you still have to use jQuery - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/A46Ka/7/)

```
$(function() {
    $(".subnavigation").find("li:gt(1)").css("border", 0);
});
```

Comment: CSS3 only, right? nth-child doesn't have native backwards support compatibility like jQuery does, right?

Comment: @Zoltan Toth You know what, come to think of it; using `.eq` would be better than `:nth-child` or `:eq` because of performance. I'm not 100%, but I don't think `:` selectors can leverage `querySelectorAll()` please correct me if i'm wrong, upvote regardless.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy actually [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/A46Ka/7/) will be the fastest, because it finds the parent and loops only through its children, instead of finding *all* the `<li>` elements on the page and checking if they a child of `.subnavigation` or not

Answer (score 0):

Also This should work

```
$("ul.subnavigation li:gt(1)").addClass("last-child");
```

Add this as you style and it should work

```
.last-child 
{
   border-right:0px !important;
}
```

Setting **!important** will override the default styles

[Check this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/A46Ka/8/)

Comment: Thanks, only thing it doesnt remove the border from the 3rd link "how to/faqs".

Comment: try this Selector $("ul.subnavigation li:gt(1)").addClass("last-child");